# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 in iOS Framework

Tags: ios, xcode

I tried to modified some settings to generate AsyncNetwork iOS framework.

(you can find the original AsyncNetwork from https://github.com/jdiehl/async-network)

But I got the following warning and error when using this framework I generated for iOS in my project:

ld: warning: ignoring file /MyProjectName/AsyncNetwork.framework/AsyncNetwork, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /MyProjectName/AsyncNetwork.framework/AsyncNetwork (2 slices)

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AsyncClient", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any suggestion? I am testing whether AsyncNetwork (based on another great library, CocoaAsyncSocket) can perform better than MCSession in data transmission.

Thank you for precious time on my question.

Comment: Usually this type of error comes as a result of certain implementation (`.m`) files not being compiled. Check the `Compile Source` build phase in your project settings and make sure that `AsyncClient.m` is being compiled. Also, if this is the issue, checking off "Add files to target" and selecting your target when importing files will help you to avoid this issue in the future.

Comment: Hi @ChrisLoonam, Thank you for the quick response. AsyncClient.m is in the Compile Source. I wonder whether the setting in Build Settings Architectures is correct. The setting I have are $(ARCHS_STANDARD). In Valid Architecture, I have arm64, armv7, armv7s. If I add x86_64 in Valid Architecture, I will get

warning: no rule to process file 'MyProjectName/GCDAsyncSocket.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture x86_64

Comment: After reporting this issue to the author of AsyncNetwork, the author resolved this issue with the newest patch. Highly recommend this library, save me a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a lipo to include some slices in same the `.a`.

There is an exemple:
`lipo -create -output lib_name.a lib_name_device.a lib_name_simulator.a`

You can find a tutorial here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial